# How to fix the received messages in Prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

When a client sends me a message, in my eshop, the received message in Prestashop, it looks like this:
"Τεστ για την".

Does anyone knows how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like this & Tau; & epsilon; & sigma; & tau; & gamma; & iota; & alpha; & tau; & eta; & nu;

Answer (score 0):

Since few months i got lot of spam too on my Prestashop.

so i did this to reduce SPAMs :

Install this module (you ll need an account on the prestashop forum) :
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=166525

Source :
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/664662-spam-depuis-le-formulaire-de-contact/

once the module is install, i had keywords in my spam list.

on each spam received i also get the ip and add it to my banned ip list on my cpanel access.

after that i clean all message related to this ip or keyword.

hope it helps.

good luck